# "selected" tag on option doesn't work when select has formControlName

Tags: select, angular

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <label class="text-color">Lokalizacja:</label>
  <select class="form-control dropdown" formControlName="localization">
    <option value="Gdańsk" selected>Gdańsk</option>
    <option value="Rzeszów">Rzeszów</option>
    <option value="Wrocław">Wrocław</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Don't know what happened but in that case there is no selected option and I have to choose something from the list. When I delete `formControlName="localization` from select, then `Gdańsk` is selected at the start.

Lokalization control looks like this `localizationCtrl = new FormControl("", Validators.required);`

there is no difference when I replace that on:
`localizationCtrl = new FormControl("");`
of course next step was to add that control to offerForm by doing:

```
...
localization: this.localizationCtrl
...
```

but please don't try to look for a problem here because I have something like 7 other validators inside offerForm and all of them work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign the default value during form model initialization.

```
`localizationCtrl = new FormControl("Gdańsk", Validators.required);`
```

or if the value is coming from the server, use formControl's `updateValue` method.

```
localizationCtrl.updateValue('Gdańsk');
```

See here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-model-driven-forms-with-formgroup-and-formcontrol and 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deal-with-different-form-controls-in-angular-2

Comment: I completely forgot what was the ```""``` inside control about. A bit embarassing, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `selected` use

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedItem" class="form-control dropdown" formControlName="localization">
```

and set `selectedItem` to `"Gdańsk"`

or set the value of `localization` to `Gdańsk`